# Functions with special separability

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose we have differentiable functions $F$, $f_1, \dots, f_n$, and $g_1, \dots, g_n$ satisfy the following relation
$$ F(x+y) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) g_i(y).$$
What are the possible forms of $F$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$, you get
$$F'(x+y)=\sum_i f_i^\prime(x)g_i(y)=\sum_i f_i(x)g_i^\prime(y).$$
Substitute to the last equality some values $y_j$ then
$$\sum_i f_i^\prime(x)g_i(y_j)=\sum_i f_i(x)g_i^\prime(y_j),\quad j=1,\ldots,n.$$
Assuming that $\det g_i(y_j)\neq 0$, solve this, and obtain
$$f_i^\prime(x)=\sum_{j} c_{i,j}f_j(x).$$
This is a system of linear equation with constant coefficients from which it follows
that $f_i$ are (generalized) exponential sums. For similar reasons, $g_i$ are also generalized exponential sums. The rest is algebra.

Comment: To be more concrete, $F$ is a solution if and only if it can be written
$$F(x)=x^{k_1}e^{\lambda_1x}+\dots +x^{k_m}e^{\lambda_m x},$$
where $\sum k_j=n$. You prove the "only if" part and the "if" part is obvious. Of course, trigonometric solutions are included by choosing $\lambda_j$ in complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: I meant of course a linear combination $C_1x^{k_1}e^{\lambda_1}+\dots$.

Comment: Or even more precisely, $C_1x^{k_1}e^{\lambda_1 x}+\ldots$ :-)